# Sass mixin doesn't take value but variable name instead

Tags: sass, mixins

I have simple calc mixin:

```
@mixin calc($what, $how, $that) {
    width: -webkit-calc($how- $that);
    width: -moz-calc($how - $that);
    width: calc($how- $that);
    width: $how;
}
```

Which I am using :

```
@include calc("width", 100%, 6px);
```

But after compiling I am getting:

```
  width: -webkit-calc($how- $that);
  width: -moz-calc($how - $that);
  width: calc($how- $that);
  width: 100%;
```

What I am doing wrong?
Why only last line is ok?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [Sass variable interpolator](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_):

```
@mixin calc($what, $how, $that) {
  width: -webkit-calc(#{$how}- #{$that});
  width: -moz-calc(#{$how}- #{$that});
  width: calc(#{$how}- #{$that});
  width: $how;
}

.sel {
  @include calc("width", 100%, 6px);
}
```

yields

```
.sel {
  width: -webkit-calc(100%- 6px);
  width: -moz-calc(100%- 6px);
  width: calc(100%- 6px);
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: awsome, thank you, can you tell me how to use $what parameter please? (to use it instead of "width" in mixin)

Comment: Same way - just replace the `width` attribute in your mixin with `#{$what}`